# Framework to populate common field in unrelated classes

Tags: java

I'm attempting to write a framework to handle an interface with an external library and its API.  As part of that, I need to populate a header field that exists with the same name and type in each of many (70ish) possible message classes.  Unfortunately, instead of having each message class derive from a common base class that would contain the header field, each one is entirely separate.

As as toy example:

```
public class A
{
   public Header header;
   public Integer aData;
}

public class B
{
   public Header header;
   public Long bData;
}
```

If they had designed them sanely where A and B derived from some base class containing the header, I could just do:

```
public boolean sendMessage(BaseType b)
{
   b.header = populateHeader();
   stuffNecessaryToSendMessage();
}
```

But as it stands, Object is the only common class. The various options I've thought of would be:

- A separate method for each type.  This would work, and be fast, but the code duplication would be depressingly wasteful.
- I could subclass each of the types and have them implement a common Interface.  While this would work, creating 70+ subclasses and then modifying the code to use them instead of the original messaging classes is a bridge too far.
- Reflection.  Workable, but I'd expect it to be too slow (performance is a concern here)

Given these, the separate method for each seems like my best bet, but I'd love to have a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you the following. Create a set of interfaces you'd like to have. For example

```
public interface HeaderHolder {
    public void setHeader(Header header);
    public Header getHeader();
}
```

I'd like your classes to implement them, i.e you's like that your class `B` is defined as

`class B implements HeaderHolder {...}`

Unfortunately it is not. Now problem!

Create facade:

```
public class InterfaceWrapper {
    public <T> T wrap(Object obj, Class<T> api) {...}
}
```

You can implement it at this phase using dynamic proxy. Yes, dynamic proxy uses reflection, but forget about this right now.

Once you are done you can use your `InterfaceWrapper` as following:

```
B b = new B();
new IntefaceWrapper().wrap(b, HeaderHolder.class).setHeader("my header");
```

As you can see now you can set headers to any class you want (if it has appropriate property). Once you are done you can check your performance. If and only if usage of reflection in dynamic proxy is a bottleneck change the implementation to code generation (e.g. based on custom annotation, package name etc). There are a lot of tools that can help you to do this or alternatively you can implement such logic yourself. The point is that you can always change implementation of `IntefaceWrapper` without changing other code.

But avoid premature optimization. Reflection works very efficiently these days. Sun/Oracle worked hard to achieve this. They for example create classes on the fly and cache them to make reflection faster. So probably taking in consideration the full flow the reflective call does not take too much time.

Answer (score 1):

The only library I know of that can do this [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).  It does use reflection, but the good news is that it'll be easier to test if it's slow than to write your own reflection code to discover that it's slow.

By default, dozer will call the same getter/setters on two objects even if they are completely different.  You can configure it in much more complex ways though.  For example, you can also tell it to access the fields directly.  You can give it a custom converter to convert a Map to a List, things like that.

You can just take one populated instance, or perhaps even your own `BaseType` and say, `dozer.map(baseType, SubType.class);`

Answer (score 1):

How about dynamically generating those 70+ subclasses in the build time of your project ? That way you won't need to maintain 70+ source files while keeping the benefits of the approach from your second bullet.

Comment: That'd definitely help, but I'd still need to modify existing code that works with the library's versions to instead use the subclass ones, correct?

Comment: Yes, only the subclasses would have those header setters.